# How to pop up a minimized wxPython window

Tags: popup, wxpython

I have a utility where I want it to pop up to the front of the screen from time to time to request user input.

(I know it is very annoying general behavior but I have good reasons in this case.)

I have found the RequestUserAttention method that can be used for a more pleasant request for input from the user but in my case I just want it to pop up a window.

Maybe even modal on top of all the other windows.

The platform here is XP if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should think about your reasons again, but anyway:

```
frame.Show()
frame.Raise() 
frame.Iconize(False)
```

should raise the frame.

Comment: This does not seem to work. (At least on XP.)
In my case I really have a wx.Frame that has been minimized (iconified)

Comment: Edited my answer to incorporate your comment (I hope).